# Почему программа, написанная с потоками, работает гораздо медленнее обычной?

Tags: linux, c, многопоточность

Программа сравнивает строки и выводит процент схожести

Без потоков:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

static int res = 0;
static int col_words = 0;

int process(char *s, char *S2)
{ 
    char *instr;
    int col_in = 0;
    double proc; 
    instr = strstr(S2,s); 
    col_words++;
    if(instr!=NULL)
    {
     res += strlen(s);
    }
    else res += 0; 
    proc = (res+col_words-1)*100/strlen(S2);
    printf("%.1lf\n",proc);  

}

int main()
{

char S1[2000] = "aaa bvbb cc bb gg sdsdf", S2[2000] = "aaa bvbb";
    char sp[10]=" ";
    char *istr;
    //int res = 0, col_words=0, tmp;
    double proc; 

    clock_t time;
    time = clock();

    if(strlen(S1)<=strlen(S2))
    {
    istr = strtok(S1,sp);
    while(istr != NULL)
    {
       process(istr,S2);
       istr = strtok(NULL,sp);
       //col_words++;
    } 
    //proc = (res+col_words-1)*100/strlen(S2);
    }

    //printf("%.1lf\n",proc);  

    time = clock() - time;
    printf("time - %f\n", (double)time/CLOCKS_PER_SEC); 

    return 0;

}
```

С потоками:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

pthread_mutex_t mtx; 
static int res = 0;
static int col_words = 0;

typedef struct{
   char slovo[20];
   char str[2000];
} pthrData;


void* process(void* thread_data)
{ 
    pthrData *data = (pthrData*) thread_data;

    //pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);


    col_words++;
    char *instr;
    double proc;
    instr = strstr(data->str,data->slovo);
    if(instr!=NULL)
    {
      res += strlen(data->slovo);
    }  

    proc = (res+col_words-1)*100/strlen(data->str);  
    printf("%.2lf\n",proc); 


    //pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);

}

int main()
{

    pthread_mutex_init(&mtx,NULL);         

char S1[2000] = "aaa bvbb cc bb gg", S2[2000] = "aaa bvbb";
    char sp[10]=" ";
    char words[2000][2000];
    char *istr;
    int res = 0, col_w=0, tmp, j=0;
    double proc;  

//printf("Enter S1, S2\n");
    //gets(S1);
    //gets(S2);

clock_t time;
    time = clock();



    istr = strtok(S1,sp); 
    while(istr != NULL)
    {
     col_w++;
     strncpy(words[j],istr,2000);
     istr = strtok(NULL,sp);
     j++;
    }

    pthread_t* threads = (pthread_t*) malloc(col_w * sizeof(pthread_t));
    pthrData* threadData = (pthrData*) malloc(col_w * sizeof(pthrData));
    for(int i=0;i<col_w;i++)
    {
       strncpy(threadData[i].slovo,words[i],2000);
       strncpy(threadData[i].str,S2,2000);

       pthread_create(&(threads[i]),NULL,process,&threadData[i]);


    }
    for(int i=0;i<col_w;i++)
    {
       pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);     
    }
    free(threads);
    free(threadData);



    time = clock() - time;
    printf("time - %f\n", (double)time/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    return 0;

}
```

С потоками работает медленнее. Время выполнения сильно отличается, как минимум в 2 раза. Программы запускал на виртуалке vmware, на ubuntu последней версии, но я думаю, что дело не в этом.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55661/discussion-on-question-by--------).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По сути, данная программа подсчитывает количество слов для поиска и сумму длинн найденных слов, которые хотя бы один раз встретились в тексте.

Наверное, для определения схожести текста с набором заданных слов, несколько лучше было бы искать все вхождения слов в текст, определяя таким образом, какая часть текста покрывается данными словами.

Впрочем, вопрос, как мне кажется, скорее относится к *эфективной* реализации подобных действий в *многопоточной* программе.

В общем случае, чем больше полезной работы выполняет каждый поток, тем более эффективна будет программа в целом. В частности, надо стараться уменьшить количество синхронизирующих взаимодействий (использование mutex, condition variables и т.п.) между потоками.

К счастью, данная программа по своей сути именно такая, она позволяет показать, как можно независимо разделить всю работу по поиску вхождения слов в текст и подсчет некоторй статистики совершенно без взаимодействия потоков.

Идея состоит в том, что перед поиском мы создадим массив слов и запустим заданное количество потоков, каждый из которых, основываясь на переданном ему его прядковом номере, будет вычислять какие слова из массива он будет искать в тексте, не пересекаясь с другими потоками. То же самое относится и к результатам работы каждого потока, которые тот создает в отведенном для его номера элементе массива, не взаимодействуя с другими потоками.

Затем, первоначальный поток (main) дожидается завершения всех остальных и собирает частичные суммы, накопленные каждым из потоков вместе.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

// Вернем количество байт, которые word занимает в text
// и увеличим общий счетчик вхождений слов в текст
size_t
lookup_word (char *word, size_t wlen, size_t *tot_cnt, char *text)
{
  char *instr;
  size_t res = 0;

  if (wlen)
    while ((instr = strstr(text, word))) {
      res += wlen;
      text = instr + wlen;
      (*tot_cnt)++;
    }

  return res;
}

// аргументы и результат работы каждого потока
// поток ищет в text слова из массива words с индексами кратными номеру потока
struct thrdata {
  int nthr,    // общее число потоков
    i_thr;     // номер текущего потока
  char *text;  // текст 
  struct words *words; // массив слов  для поиска

  // результат работы потока
  size_t n_words, // количество найденных слов
    tot_cnt,      // сумма вхождений слов в текст
    s_len;        // их общий размер в тексте

  pthread_t tid; 
};

// дескриптор массива слов
struct words {
  struct wstr *warr; // массив дескрипторов слов
  size_t n_words;    // его размер
};

struct wstr {
  char *wtxt;  // байты слова (nil-terminated)
  size_t wlen; // длина слова (strlen)
};

/*
  В каждом потоке ищем слова с индексом кратным номеру потока
  Количество найденных слов и общая найденная длина 
  возвращаются в переданной структуре (*arg)
 */
void *
process (void *arg)
{
  struct thrdata *d = (__typeof__(d))arg;
  d->s_len = d->n_words = d->tot_cnt = 0;
  size_t res;

  for (int i = d->i_thr; i < d->words->n_words; i += d->nthr)
    if ((res = lookup_word(d->words->warr[i].wtxt,
                           d->words->warr[i].wlen,
                           &d->tot_cnt,
                           d->text))) {
      d->s_len += res;
      d->n_words++;
    }

  return (void *)0;
}

char *
make_text (char *s, size_t nrep)
{
  size_t l = strlen(s);
  char *t = malloc(l * nrep + 1);
  if (t)
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nrep; i++)
      strcpy(t + i * l, s);

  return t;
}


#define INICAP_WORDS 1
int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char S1[2000] = "aaa bvbb cc bb gg sdsdf 123 567",
    S2[2000] = "aaa bvbb";
  char sp[10]=" ";
  char *istr;

  clock_t time;

  /*
    сделаем из S1[] массив слов (указатель на начало и длина слова)
    и найдем их количество
    Внимние(!) strtok() модифицирует содержимое S1[]
  */
  struct words wrds = {0};
  size_t wrds_capacity;
  if (!(wrds.warr = malloc((wrds_capacity = INICAP_WORDS) *
                           sizeof(struct wstr))))
        exit((perror("malloc"), 2));

  for (istr = strtok(S1,sp); istr; wrds.n_words++, istr = strtok(NULL, sp)) {
    if (wrds.n_words == wrds_capacity)
      if (!(wrds.warr = realloc(wrds.warr,
                                (wrds_capacity *= 2) * sizeof(struct wstr))))
        exit((perror("realloc"), 2));
    wrds.warr[wrds.n_words].wtxt = istr;
    wrds.warr[wrds.n_words].wlen = strlen(istr);
  }

  // определим число потоков 
  int nthr = atoi(av[1] ? av[1] : "0");
  if (nthr < 1)
    if ((nthr = sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN)) < 1)
      nthr = 4; // не сконфигурировано или лимит не установлен
  // число повторений текста
  int nt = 1;
  if (av[1] && av[2])
    if ((nt = atoi(av[2])) < 1)
      nt = 1;
  char *Text = make_text(S2, nt);
  printf("Text %zu bytes\n", strlen(Text));

  // sequential test
  time = clock();
  size_t res = 0,
    tot_cnt = 0,
    wcnt = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < wrds.n_words; i++) {
    size_t old = res;
    res += lookup_word(wrds.warr[i].wtxt, wrds.warr[i].wlen, &tot_cnt,
                       Text);
    if (res > old)
      wcnt++;
  }
  time = clock() - time;
  puts("Sequential");
  printf("found %zu (%zu times) of total %zu words  res = %zu bytes\n",
         wcnt, tot_cnt, wrds.n_words, res);
  printf("time: %f sec\n", (double)time/CLOCKS_PER_SEC); 

  // multithread test
  printf("run %d threads\n", nthr);
  struct thrdata tdata[nthr];

  time = clock();
  // заполним аргументы для потоков и запустим их
  for (int i = 0; i < nthr; i++) {
    tdata[i].nthr = nthr;
    tdata[i].i_thr = i;
    tdata[i].text = Text;
    tdata[i].words = &wrds;
    pthread_create(&tdata[i].tid, NULL, process, tdata + i);
  }

  // соберем результаты всех потоков
  res = tot_cnt = wcnt = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < nthr; i++) {
    if (pthread_join(tdata[i].tid, 0) == 0) {
      res += tdata[i].s_len;
      wcnt += tdata[i].n_words;
      tot_cnt += tdata[i].tot_cnt;
    }
  }


  time = clock() - time;
  free(wrds.warr);

  puts("Threading");
  printf("found %zu (%zu times) of total %zu words  res = %zu bytes\n",
         wcnt, tot_cnt, wrds.n_words, res);
  printf("time: %f sec\n", (double)time/CLOCKS_PER_SEC); 

  return 0;

}
```

Что же касается демонстрации ускорения подобной многопоточной прграммы над однопоточной, то нужо взять побольше данных (особенно размер текста).
(попозже попробую продемонстрировать это и найти точку равной эффективности)

**Update**

Модифицировал программку. Теперь она сначала выдает результат (время) выполнения в последовательном, а затем в многопоточном варианте. Первый параметр -- количество потоков, второй -- множитель для размера текста (переменная `S2[]`). Также добавил в `S1[]` пару слов для поиска, чтобы равномерно загружать потоки в 4-х (8-ми) ядерном CPU.

Например:

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ gcc w-thr.c -pthread -O2
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./a.out 4 1000
Text 8000 bytes
Sequential
found 3 (3000 times) of total 8 words  res = 9000 bytes
time: 0.000056 sec
run 4 threads
Threading
found 3 (3000 times) of total 8 words  res = 9000 bytes
time: 0.000237 sec
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./a.out 4 10000
Text 80000 bytes
Sequential
found 3 (30000 times) of total 8 words  res = 90000 bytes
time: 0.000534 sec
run 4 threads
Threading
found 3 (30000 times) of total 8 words  res = 90000 bytes
time: 0.000253 sec
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./a.out 4 50000
Text 400000 bytes
Sequential
found 3 (150000 times) of total 8 words  res = 450000 bytes
time: 0.002502 sec
run 4 threads
Threading
found 3 (150000 times) of total 8 words  res = 450000 bytes
time: 0.000447 sec
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ grep CPU /proc/cpuinfo 
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ uname -a
Linux avp-ubu1 4.4.0-66-generic #87-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 3 15:29:05 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

В общем, поиграйтесь с различной длиной текста и количеством потоков.

(обратите внимание, что начиная с некоторого большого размера текста (на одной машине 1.5Мб, на другой 8Мбайт), результаты снова становятся практически  равными (это играет роль скорость обмена между основной памятью и кэшем процессора))

**Update 2** (упрощенный вариант, используем внешние массивы для данных потоков)

```
#define NWORDS 2000

char *word[NWORDS];
size_t n_words = 0,
  nthr;
char *text;
struct thresult {
  // результат работы потока
  size_t n_words, // количество найденных слов
    tot_cnt,      // сумма вхождений слов в текст
    s_len;        // их общий размер в тексте
} tres[NWORDS];
```

Очевидно, что не имеет смысла закладывать больше потоков, чем максимальное количество слов, поэтому константа `NWORDS` используется для обеих.

Теперь функция потока `process` несколько меняется и в качестве аргумента получает сразу номер потока (приведенный к `void *`).

```
void *
process (void *a)
{
  size_t tix = (size_t)a,
    res;

  tres[tix] = (struct thresult){0};
  for (size_t i = tix; i < n_words; i += nthr) {
    size_t wlen = strlen(word[i]);
    if ((res = lookup_word(word[i], wlen, &tres[tix].tot_cnt, text))) {
      tres[tix].s_len += res;
      tres[tix].n_words++;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Также небольшие изменения в `main`, упрощается создание списка слов,  меняются циклы создания потока и сборки результата.
(для краткости я полностью выбросил вызов подсчета в одном (главном) потоке)

```
int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char S1[2000] = "aaa bvbb cc bb gg sdsdf 123 567",
    S2[2000] = "aaa bvbb";
  char sp[10]=" ";
  char *istr;

  clock_t time;


  /*
    сделаем из S1[] массив слов (указатель на начало и длина слова)
    и найдем их количество (в extern n_words !!!)
    Внимние(!) strtok() модифицирует содержимое S1[]
  */
  for (istr = strtok(S1,sp);
       n_words < NWORDS && istr;
       n_words++, istr = strtok(NULL, sp))
    word[n_words] = istr;

  // определим число потоков (в extern nthr !!!)
  nthr = atoi(av[1] ? av[1] : "0");
  if (nthr < 1)
    if ((nthr = sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN)) < 1)
      nthr = 4; // не сконфигурировано или лимит не установлен
  if (nthr >= NWORDS)
    nthr = NWORDS - 1;
  // число повторений текста
  int nt = 1;
  if (av[1] && av[2])
    if ((nt = atoi(av[2])) < 1)
      nt = 1;
  text = make_text(S2, nt);
  printf("Text %zu bytes\n", strlen(text));
  printf("run %zu threads\n", nthr);

  time = clock();
  pthread_t tid[nthr];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < nthr; i++)
    pthread_create(tid + i, NULL, process, (void *)i);

  size_t res = 0,
    tot_cnt = 0,
    wcnt = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < nthr; i++) 
    if (pthread_join(tid[i], 0) == 0) {
      res += tres[i].s_len;
      wcnt += tres[i].n_words;
      tot_cnt += tres[i].tot_cnt;
    }

  time = clock() - time;
  printf("found %zu (%zu times) of total %zu words  res = %zu bytes\n",
     wcnt, tot_cnt, n_words, res);
  printf("time: %f sec\n", (double)time/CLOCKS_PER_SEC); 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: А попробуйте запустить мой код (тот, что я приложил в задании) на своей машине и сообщить мне время выполнения, а то у меня всего 1 ядро и я не могу достичь прироста в скорости

Comment: @ВадимМороз, тот код, что мы видим в тексте вопроса?

Comment: @ВадимМороз, если тот, то без потоков `time - 0.000004`, а с потоками `time - 0.000005` (кстати, я подправил размер в строке 76, чтобы компилятор не ругался).

Comment: @ВадимМороз  и еще, я немного посмотрел на ваш код. Так вот, из-за `if(strlen(S1)<=strlen(S2))` ни один поток у вас не запускается, поэтому и время практически равно времени без потоков. Если это условие выбросить, то запускается 6 потоков (как и задумано у вас, по одному потоку на каждое слово), но программа работает `time - 0.000658`

Comment: @avp Я об этом же 12 марта написал ;)

Comment: @0andriy, в том, что я не внимателен к комментариям нет ничего страшного, а вот ТС мог бы и подправить вопрос в соответствии с ними

Comment: @avp да, ваша программа с потоками работает в разы быстрее, но этот код пока слишком сложный для меня. нельзя ли как-то упростить, или что-то изменить в моем коде с потоками, чтобы работало хотя бы немного быстрее?

Comment: @ВадимМороз, давайте попробуем упростить. Что именно не понятно в этом коде? 1) Как делаем массив указателей на слова (malloc/realloc)? 2) Код функции process (и если да, что именно)? 3) Код функции lookup_word? Или вообще идея, которую реализует программа?

Comment: @ВадимМороз, предполагая, что вы могли запутаться в хитросплетении структур данных и их передаче в `process()` написал упрощенный вариант с extern данными, разделяемыми main и всеми потоками. Надеюсь, теперь код проще для понимания.

Comment: Что не хочет компилироваться 2-й вариант. В чем м б дело?
./Desktop/zadanie2.c: In function ‘process’:
./Desktop/zadanie2.c:33:16: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘lookup_word’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
if ((res = lookup_word(word[i], wlen, &tres[tix].tot_cnt, text))) {
^~~~~~~~~~~
./Desktop/zadanie2.c: In function ‘main’:
./Desktop/zadanie2.c:76:10: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘make_text’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
text = make_text(S2, nt);

Comment: ./Desktop/zadanie2.c:76:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
text = make_text(S2, nt);
/tmp/ccB6yJpu.o: In function `process':
zadanie2.c:(.text+0x80): undefined reference to `lookup_word'
/tmp/ccB6yJpu.o: In function `main':
zadanie2.c:(.text+0x32d): undefined reference to `make_text'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Естественно, возьмите `lookup_word`, `make_text` нужные .h и что там еще пропущено из основного (я думал, это очевидно) (и не забудьте компилировать с -pthread)

Comment: Ага, запустил, непонятно как определяется число потоков начиная от // определим число потоков (в extern nthr !!!)
  nthr = atoi(av[1] ? av[1] : "0");   За что вообще отвечает массив av? Еще непонятно почему вместо обычного int везде size_t?

Comment: Массив `av[]` это аргументы командной строки. Этот массив формируется ОС и завершается NULL (`av[ac] == NULL`).  Далее смотрим заданы ли вообще аргументы, если да, то в `atoi()` передаем первый (av[1]), если нет, то `"0"` (в atoi надо передавать строки). size_t я взял (кроме того, что именно его правильно использовать для индексов массивов, размеров строк и т.п.), еще и поскольку его размер такой же, как у указателя, к которому мы приводим номер потока при вызове pthread_create

Comment: Что-то все-ровно не совсем понимаю алгоритм нахождения количества потоков. Тут суть в том, чтобы создать количество потоков равное количеству ядер процессора? И еще, не могли бы вы написать отдельно таким же алгоритмом, но без потоков, как вы делали в одной программе, а то у меня не получается, плохо чужом коде разбираюсь, тем более в новой для меня теме.

Comment: В первом аргументе вызова программы задаем желаемое число потоков. Если после atoi получили 0 (например в первом аргументе не число (или вообще нет аргументов командной строки)), то берем количество потоков равное количеству ядер (вызываем sysconf). Если вызов sysconf неудачен, то будем делать 4 потока. А без потоков, так это же в первой программе в начале ответа (часть кода, отмеченная комментарием `// sequential test`) (а разбираться в чужом коде -- учитесь. Вставляйте printf в непонятные места и запускайте. Или пройдите его в отладчике (gdb). Для этого оттранслируйте с -g и без оптимизации)

Comment: Так если из первой задачи удалить реализацию потоками, то получится не честно, т к массивы по разному объявляются, под что-то выделяется память, под что-то нет. Я попытался переделать вторую задачу без потоков, просто вызвав функцию lookup_words, как вы делали в первой, но выдает ошибку segmentation fault(core dumped). Может глянете, все-таки ваш код, а то я эту лабу уже месяц сдать не могу http://pastebin.com/gegu7spE

Comment: Наверное (сейчас проверять некогда), вот тут `lookup_word(word[n_words], strlen(word[n_words]), &tot_cnt,
S2);` ошибка. / Надо `lookup_word(word[i], strlen(word[i]), &tot_cnt,
Text);`

Comment: ага, всё верно, теперь работает

Comment: Хорошо. Успеха при сдаче лабы!

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @avp, одно я все-таки не могу понять. как работает сам поток и поточная функция. я думал, что в один поток нужно передавать первую половину слов, а в другой - вторую половину, чтобы они вместе считали слова, но в вашем примере как-то по-другому. так как же на самом деле правильно их использовать?

Comment: Можно сделать и как вы думали и это тоже будет правильно. Если у нас N слов и K потоков, то каждый будет обрабатывать N/K слов. Потоки тоже не будут мешать друг другу. Только надо специально рассчитывать какой кусок массива достанется последнему. У меня же каждый поток просто идет по массиву начиная со своего индекса с шагом равным числу потоков до N (мне показалось, что так проще).

Comment: Ага, понял, да, действительно, так проще, спасибо)

Answer (score 5):

Ну вот, все и решилось...

*у меня в ubuntu в настройках виртуалки стоит только 1 ядро*

Понимаете, бессмысленно делать параллельность на одном ядре. Это ядро должно выполнить все то, что у вас делалось в однопоточной программе (и только по очереди - оно же одно!), плюс выполнить всю работу по созданию потоков, плюс - если потоки длинные  еще их и переключать...

Так что все понятно. Выигрыша не будет никакого, кроме проигрыша...

Потоков вообще не рекомендуется делать больше, чем ядер - с единственным исключением: когда поток что-то ожидает, скажем, от контроллера, и в это время работает другой поток. Случай не ваш.

А вычислительные потоки будут только мешать друг другу, если их больше, чем число ядер.

Answer (score 3):

- Во-первых, нет смысла сравнивать производительность относительно элементарных кусков кода, если они отличаются наличием относительно "тяжелых" операций.

  В вашем многопоточном варианте присутствуют вызовы функции `strncpy` с заведомо большим значением лимита размера: `2000` при том, что ваши слова состоят всего из 2-5 символов. Если вы представляете, что такое `strncpy` и что эта функция на самом деле делает, то вы должны понимать, что эти вызовы будут делать типичную для `stncpy` "дурную работу", т.е. заниматься обнулением сравнительно большого неиспользуемого хвоста массива. Учитывая, что ваши входные слова на порядки короче, чем `2000`, уже этого вполне достаточно, чтобы замедлить вашу реализацию с `strncpy` *в разы*.

  Первый вариант не занимается тупым вываливанием в память почти `N * 6K` нулей (где `N` - количество слов), а второй - занимается. Неудивительно, что второй вариант работает намного медленнее.
- Во-вторых, вы делаете

  ```
  strncpy(threadData[i].slovo,words[i],2000);
  ```

  при том, что `threadData[i].slovo` - это просто `char [20]` (!). То есть каждый такой `strncpy` просто вылетает за пределы массива и тупо бомбит нулями аж чуть ли не 2K чужой памяти за пределами этого массива. О чем вообще можно говорить в такой программе? Программа мертва чуть менее, чем полностью и какие-то замеры ее производительности - бесмысленны.

Comment: @Mike, Исправил, все-ровно работает медленнее. При малых строках время ровно, при больших - с потоками в 10 раз медленнее. В настройках виртуалки выставил 4 процессора, сама ubuntu стала работать быстро, а с потоками быстрее не стало

Comment: @Вадим Мороз: Не видя, что вы там наваяли в новом варианте, судить трудно.

Comment: Проще говоря, я скопировал задачу с потоками и убрал там функции для работы с потоками, чтобы поставить обе задачи в равные условия, со всеми функциями.

Comment: Оригинальные в посте программы делают всё одинаково, а именно, ничего не делают! (Обратите внимание на `if (strlen(S1) <= strlen(S2))`) И вот тут странности.

Answer (score 3):

Не могу больше на это смотреть :) Вот, набросал вариантик. Надеюсь, не сильно накосячил. Мелочи вылизывать лень.

Важное замечание: данные для всех потоков одни и те же. Изменяемая в них часть - только позиция текущего обрабатываемого потоком слова. Точно так же (в этой же структуре) можно расшарить и аналитику, что там и как считается не вникал. Очевидные обработки ошибок тоже пропущены.

На самом деле тут просто реализация разгребания очереди несколькими потоками, где в качестве очереди выступает массив слов. То же самое можно сделать на основе очереди или стека (в смысле контейнеров таких).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>

#define DELIMITERS  " \t\r\n"

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
static const char **split_2_words(char *string)
{
    const char **words = NULL;
    size_t size = 0;
    char *word = strpbrk(string, DELIMITERS);
    /*
     * Считаем количество слов в строке. Может насчитаться больше
     * (из-за сдвоеных разделителей), но не меньше.
     */
    while (word) {
        size++;
        word = strpbrk(word + 1, DELIMITERS);
    }

    if ((words = calloc(sizeof(const char *), size + 2))) {
        size = 0;
        word = strtok(string, DELIMITERS);
        while (word) {
            words[size++] = word;
            word = strtok( NULL, DELIMITERS);
        }
    }

    return words;
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
typedef struct _thread_data
{
    const char **sentence_words;
    const char **words_2_find;
    size_t current_word;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
} thread_data;

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
static void * process(void *_data)
{
    thread_data *data = (thread_data *) _data;

    while (data) {

        size_t current_word;
        pthread_mutex_lock(&data->mutex);
        if (data->words_2_find[data->current_word]) {
            current_word = data->current_word;
            ++data->current_word;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&data->mutex);
        }
        else {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&data->mutex);
            break;
        }
        for (size_t idx = 0; data->sentence_words[idx]; idx++) {
            if (strstr(data->sentence_words[idx], data->words_2_find[current_word])) {
                printf("Word '%s' found in '%s'\n", data->words_2_find[current_word],
                    data->sentence_words[idx]);
            }
        }
    }

    return _data;
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
int main()
{
    char *sentence = readline("Enter sentence: ");
    char *words = readline("Enter words to find: ");
    const char **sentence_words = split_2_words(sentence);
    const char **words_2_find = split_2_words(words);
    thread_data *data = malloc(sizeof(thread_data));
    size_t nthreads = (size_t) sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);
    pthread_t *threads = calloc(nthreads, sizeof(pthread_t));

    data->sentence_words = sentence_words;
    data->words_2_find = words_2_find;
    data->current_word = 0;
    pthread_mutex_init(&data->mutex, NULL);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nthreads; i++) {
        pthread_create(threads + i, NULL, process, data);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nthreads; i++) {
        pthread_join(*(threads + i), NULL);
    }

    free(sentence);
    free(words);
    free(sentence_words);
    free(words_2_find);
    free(data);
    free(threads);
    printf("That's All, Folks!\n");
    return 0;
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
```

Comment: Вы используете `data->current_word` вне критической секции, стоит заменить на `current_word`(оно ведь может измениться между if и printf). Присваивание в `current_word` также может породить race_condition, нужно залочить. (и возможно сразу и проинкрементировать?)

Comment: А, точно. Поправлю.

Comment: Ым... Какой-то идеи не увидел, но вижу, что инкрементирование `data->current_word` происходит только в одном месте - на старте каждого потока. А дальше что? Запущено 5 потоков, надо обработать 100 слов - величина `data->current_word` никогда не вырастает больше 5 - все потоки затыкаются в бесконечных циклах. Ясно, что после обработки каждого слова поток должен получить следующее и не забыть увеличить `data->current_word` (!). Но здесь уже надо быть осторожным, чтобы не выгнать `data->current_word` за пределы массива.

Comment: Второй баг (из примерно той же оперы) - если количество потоков изначально *больше* количества слов, то "лишние" потоки на старте будут тупо вылетать  за пределы массива слов, ибо никакой проверки на это не сделано.

Comment: @AnT, спать мне пора, это уже глюки :) По-хорошему надо бы ещё проверять что не вылетели за размер массива слов. (пока правил исходник и этот коммент прилетел) Возможно, проще было бы ввести отдельный счётчик элементов, а не ориентироваться на последний нулевой указатель.

Comment: Что-то перемудрили с инкрементом, не? Проще считать, что `data->current_word` указывает на следующее слово. В крит.секции берём это следующее слово(если оно есть), потом инкрементим. Что в начале, что в цикле, без разницы. Смысл операции один: взять след. слово, переместить указатель.

Comment: @vp_arth, да пока ковырялся мозг оплавился :)

Comment: А для `data` `malloc()` зачем? (да  и для `trheads` тоже)

Comment: @avp, с `data` это ошмёток отладки других вариантов. А `threads` как  без динамики?

Comment: Просто `pthread_t threads[nthreads];`. Далее менять ничего не надо

Comment: @avp, VLA же, не?

Comment: Да. А в linux есть компиляторы, которые VLA не понимают?